# What regular expression I have to use in regular expression extractor?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have the following response in JMeter:

{"**id":"140**","rsd":null,"col":"green","cc":"B5307F","pn":"KENWAY TYRES RENEWAL 2014","loc":"ABD - LR / L3 / L3","**isf":"1**","**isl":"0**","tq":"15","pi":null,"**st":"1**","dsid":"15","cid":"2120","spl":null,"wid":"WI/3ivdfzhg","inv":null,"pdid":"1103","di":"0","pl":"0"}

I need to extract the value of id, when isf=1, isl=0 and st=1. What regular expression I have to use in regular expression extractor?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?=.*?isf":"1)(?=.*?isl":"0)(?=.*?st":"1)id":"(\d+)
```

Try this.Just grab the first group.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/5

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now in the same case, if I need to check if the st=5 or 6 or 7 and extract the id, How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PreminiFrancis (?=.*?st":"1|5|6|7)

Comment: Please look into the below case.

Comment: @preminifrancis please post a new question

Comment: I have posted as a new question.Here is the link. http://stackoverflow.com/q/26077540/4049148

Comment: @PreminiFrancis check the answer at your post

Comment: Can u pls look into my new question and provide your suggestion. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/q/26116584/4049148 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The given text formats is

```
{"id":"140","rsd":null,"col":"green","cc":"B5307F","pn":"KENWAY TYRES RENEWAL 2014","loc":"ABD - LR / L3 / L3","isf":"1","isl":"0","tq":"15","pi":null,"st":"1","dsid":"15","cid":"2120","spl":null,"wid":"WI/3ivdfzhg","inv":null,"pdid":"1103","di":"0","pl":"0"}
```

We need to create the regular expression formats to extract the id values with the following conditions

```
"isf":"1" and "isl":"0" and "st":"1"
```

The Regular expression formats to get the id values when the condition values are true

Regular Expressions formats

```
"id":"(.+)".+"isf":"1","isl":"0",.+"st":"1"
```