# Selecting matches according to the condition given using regular expression in JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

If I have a response as follows:

```
{"id":"140","rsd":null,"col":"green","cc":"B5307F","pn":"KENWAY TYRES RENEWAL 2014","loc":"ABD - LR / L3 / L3","isf":"1","isl":"0","tq":"15","pi":null,"st":"1","dsid":"15","cid":"2120","spl":null,"wid":"WI/3ivdfzhg","inv":null,"pdid":"1103","di":"0","pl":"0"}{"id":"141","rsd":null,"col":"green","cc":"B5307F","pn":"KENWAY TYRES RENEWAL 2014","loc":"ABD - LR / L3 / L3","isf":"1","isl":"0","tq":"15","pi":null,"st":"7","dsid":"15","cid":"2120","spl":null,"wid":"WI/3ivdfzhg","inv":null,"pdid":"1103","di":"0","pl":"0"}
```

and if I need to `check st=7` and `inv=null` and extract only 141 not 140.

How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO: I would recommend to use JSON parser (using BSF PostProcessor or plugin for JMeter to parse JSON).

Comment: I am new to Jmeter. I didn know how to use it. Can you please help me on this.

Comment: Can u pls look into my new question and provide your suggestion. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/q/26116584/4049148 Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PreminiFrancis did this work?this question?

Comment: Ya.. But I made few changes.  I wanted to use inv similar to st. Instead of (?=.*?inv":null)(?=(?:(?!st).)*?st":"7)"id":"(\d+) I used (?=(?:(?!inv).)*?inv":null(?=(?:(?!st).)*?st":"7)"id":"(\d+).

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=.*?inv":null)(?=(?:(?!st).)*?st":"7)"id":"(\d+)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/68

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using other websites to check regular expression result of JMETER, you can directly use Listener>View result tree and in drop down, you can select Regex tester in place of Text so that you will get accurate result. I am attaching image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYJOO.png)